# Regex in java for semicolon and comma as delimiter but also considered in the string

Tags: java, regex, lexical-analysis

I have written a lexical analyzer program in java. I am splitting the input string with a whitespace or a semicolon, but what I really wish to do is consider a semicolon or a comma as a separate token even if there is no space before it.

Right now I have
`arr = (str).split("[; ]");`

But when I am giving the input string as
`return a = 25;`

The string is split like : `[return, a, =, 25]`
It's not recognizing ; or using it as a delimiter. I tried to find a regex for it but I can't find the one that works. I am trying to avoid StringTokenizer but if it's something that should be used and can't be avoided, please let me know. I am fairly new to regex so I am not able to figure it out.

I tried the regex `((?<=;)|(?=;))` but it only splits with ; no whitespace is considered.

Comment: Maybe `\s+|(?<=;)(?!$)|(?<!^)(?=;)` can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using complex, costly lookaheads and lookbehinds, I would just use a word boundary:

```
String[] tokens = str.split(" *\\b *");
```

This will return spaces as tokens, but you can remove them easily enough:

```
tokens = Arrays.stream(tokens)
    .filter(t -> !t.isBlank()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

You can also do it in one step using [splitAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
String[] tokens = Pattern.compile(" *\\b *").splitAsStream(str)
    .filter(t -> !t.isBlank()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Yes, this helps me better. No need to add unnecessary whitespaces in input. thanks